# Jupyter notebook can't find kernels for conda environments from nb_conda_kernels

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I use different conda environments for different Python projects, and used to happily use [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) to access kernels for those environments in the Jupyter notebook. They would be available in the 'New' drop-down with names like `Python [conda env:project42]`. After some updates, none of these kernels are showing up in Jupyter, and when I try to open a notebook that had been using one of these kernels I get `Kernel not found - Could not find a kernel matching Python [conda env:project42] *. Please select a kernel:`. The only option is `Python 3`.

I've checked that all the environments are still there in conda (with `conda env list`) and that each one has the `ipykernel` package installed.

The environment where I'm launching Jupyter from has all of the following (among many others):

`ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            6.0.0                      py_0
nb_conda                  2.2.1                    py37_0
nb_conda_kernels          2.2.2                    py37_0
python                    3.7.0                h6e4f718_3`

Should I be using [jupyter_conda](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-conda/#description) instead of nb_conda? How can I see what nb_conda_kernels is trying to do or what errors it is having? I can create kernels manually but it would be time consuming to do this for every environment I have.

Any tips greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any more version/system details.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by upgrading `nb_conda_kernels` to version 2.2.3! The [release notes](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels/releases) mention that this version is a fix for `jupyter_client` 6. I created a new environment just for the notebook so it's possible there were some other factors at play as well. In the new environment I ran `conda install --channel conda-forge nb_conda_kernels` to install version 2.2.3.